# Dynamically create html pages?

Tags: php, html, dynamic

Let's consider reddit for example where people create let's say posts. Every post created has its own html page where you can see comments and etc.

I am interested in how these pages are created, I would assume that when user creates a post, when the post is authorized, its page is automatically created, but I don't have any idea how this is done. So my questions are: how is this exactly done, or am I completely wrong about the whole concept, and if so - what is the best way to do this then(create single html pages for every post authorized in the database) ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user posts the form, the page specified in the `action` will look at the logged-in user's account, determine what permissions they have, and either save the post or render a rejection message.

This is done via a database, so there will be a `user` table (containing users and their login credentials) and a `post` table (containing posts). The latter will probably have a `created_user_id` as a *foreign key* to the user table, so that each post has an owner.

How this is organised internally depends on what the site does, and how its programmers implemented it. Thus, you *might* also have a `permission` table that describes, for each user, what things they are allowed to do. This is particularly relevant at Stack Overflow, where permissions are given (or removed) based on your reputation score.

> Every post created has its own html page where you can see comments

Yes, but bear in mind that every page is created dynamically. These are (generally speaking) not stored on disk as static files: for a given page type, a script is used to render what should be seen. So if there is a story and comments, the URL is examined, the correct story found in the database, associated comments are found in the database, and then the necessary HTML containing those content items is rendered as script output.

Big sites like Reddit will use various caching strategies too (for individual fragments and whole pages) but the above is the gist of it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to learn more about server side codes based on programming languages such as PHP, Python, Perl (and many others) that generate html codes automatically (based on many factors including the user session, some data in the database, etc.) and send these dynamically generated html codes as the page source to the clients.